# Remove method with for loop python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am having below code,

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in lst:
    lst.remove(i)
```

And output is :

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

How this is possible it should print empty list because for loop iterating all elements from list and in the for loop remove will removing them.
Please help to understand.

Thanks, In advanced!